# lose special chars when include file php

Tags: php

I have file 'mod.php' like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content">
<thead>                                                 
        <td><b> Day </b></td>                           


        <td> Card </td>                                                                                             


        <td> Paypal </td>                                                                                               

</thead>
<tbody>
    [card]
    <?php foreach($this->list as $r){?>
    <tr>

         <td class="numeric"><b><?php echo $r["day"]; ?></b></td>                                                   


        <td class="numeric"><?php echo number_format($r["sum_card"],0,'',','); ?></td>                                                  


        <td class="numeric"><?php echo number_format($r["sum_paypal"],0,'',','); ?></td>                                                    
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>  
    [/card]                             
</tbody>
```

When i load it with include:

```
ob_start(); 
include ./mode.php; 
$_part = ob_get_clean();
```

then  php code  will be recognized. But when i notice the  [card][/card] disappeared.
Why??
Could someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What is `[card][/card]`? It's not a valid HTML or PHP comment. As the browser parser the document and builds the DOM, it removes illegal entries like those between <tbody> and <tr> tags.

Comment: [card][/card] is my tag. Is there anyway i keep it when i use `include`?